# How do I make it possible to control the camera in Mapbox GL JS like a 16-bit JRPG airship?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

This is me controlling the camera in Mapbox GL JS with the arrow keys on the keyboard: https://streamable.com/e/orhkbu?autoplay=1

As you can tell, it doesn't look nor feel very good. Not even any rotating -- only "strafing".

Of course, you can use the mouse to smoothly move around in a fixed area, but it doesn't look nice or smooth when moving slowly for long distances.

I want to be able to control the camera closer to something like this: https://youtu.be/iziIwwt2xiU?t=371

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to your need.
Just click on the arrow keys of the keyboard to see the changes in the map.

Reference link.
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/game-controls/